# How to add MigrateCommand while using flask built in cli?

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate, flask-cli

Earlier while using Manager from flask_script  we can add command to Manager like this.

```
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
```

Now in this new flask app I am not using flask script, so how do I add command db to like  flask run is?

Answer (score 3):

The `flask db` command is registered automatically when the extension is installed, there is nothing that you need to do on the application side.